# Election Data and Combining Gaussians

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I'm writing a paper and have this data problem from the 2012 presidential election.

In 2012, there were 4384 counties and 50 states. Obama was elected, and the standard deviation of his vote percentage from the county data is ~15 while the standard deviation from the state data is ~12.

As counties are gathered into states, variation decreases, which makes sense, and I know how to add Gaussians, but I can't quite figure out how to set this problem up.

How can I calculate the 12 from the 15? And is this similar to some standard statistics question that I can reference?  Thanks!

Comment: You can consider the state distribution as a 'mixture' of county distributions. In general, depending on circumstances, the mixture might  have either more or less variability than its components. So there is no theoretical way to model the mixture distribution without detailed information on the components. Because you have data, you can report what happened and attempt to find reasons for what you observe. But because this is politics, you can expect to have your reasons (and even in some quarters, your data) challenged.

Comment: Thanks Bruce. Yes, election data is extremely noisy. What if I took the election part out? What if you had 50 bins with 100,000 sample points in each bin and the standard deviation of the means of the sample points in each bin was 12. Then you emptied those bins into a big pile before randomly filling 5000 bins with 1,000 sample points in each bin. What would the standard deviation of the means of the sample points in each of those bins be?

You are basically integrating 5000 bins, then integrating 50 bins with the same data points in them. There should be a solution in there somewhere.

Comment: OK this is a well specified probability model. (I assumed normal data with means 100, but that assumption is not crucial to your question.) I can deal with that and give an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a population of 5 million subjects with 'scores'
$X_i$ distributed $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 100, \sigma=3795).$ [The choice of
the population mean is arbitrary because we are interested only in standard deviations.]

Step 1: They are sorted into 50 bins with 100,000 subjects each and we
take the 50 bin averages $\bar X_{100000}.$ These averages have population SD
$\sigma_1 = 3795/\sqrt{100000} \approx 12.$

Step 2: After mixing the subjects at random, we sort them a second time
into 5000 bins with 1000 subjects each and take the 5000 bin averages
$\bar X_{1000}.$ These have $\sigma_2 = 3795/\sqrt{1000} \approx 120.$

Thus with the probability model you proposed in your Comment, the averages based on
larger groups have smaller variances.

---

This can be simulated in R statistical software by using two matrices:
`MAT1` has 50 rows (bins) and 100,000 columns (subjects in each bin).
We take row averages `a1` of the 50 rows and see if the SD of these
50 averages has sample standard deviation near $\sigma_1 = 12.$ Because
there are only 50 row averages we should not expect an exact match.

Upon reapportionment, we make `MAT2` with 5000 rows (bins) and 1000 columns
and find 5000 row averages `a2` and compare the sample SD of these
row averages with $\sigma_2 = 120.$

```
set.seed(313)  # retain this row to repeat exact same simul, delete for fresh run
x1 = rnorm(5*10^6, 100, 3795)  # 5 million subject scores
MAT1 = matrix(x1, nrow=50);  dim(MAT1)
[1]     50 100000              # verify matrix is 50 x 100000
a1 = rowMeans(MAT1)            # 50 row means
summary(a1);  length(a1);  sd(a1)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   59.33   89.22   95.40   96.25  104.50  129.60 
[1] 50
[1] 13.68891                   # reasonably close to 12
x2 = sample(x1)                # scramble subjects
MAT2 = matrix(x2, nrow=5000);  dim(MAT2)
[1] 5000 1000 
a2 = rowMeans(MAT2)
summary(a2);  length(a2);  sd(a2)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-386.10   15.35   99.00   96.25  176.50  625.60 
[1] 5000
[1] 119.859                    # close to 120
```

The only difference between the simulation procedure and your political data is that the subjects
in states are not randomly scrambled into counties. But the simulation
accurate imitation of the scenario you proposed in your comment.

*Addendum* per Comment: If one has a random sample of observations $X_i$ with $E(X_i)=\mu$ and $SD(X_i) = \sigma$ and one using a sample mean $\bar X$ to estimate the the population mean $\mu,$ then the standard deviation $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n}$ is called the 'standard error of the mean'. Sometimes $\sigma$ is unknown and so estimated by the sample standard deviation
$S = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2}.$ Then the estimated
standard error $S/\sqrt{n}$ is also called the 'standard error'. (The word 'estimated' is dropped, when obvious from context, and sometimes even when not obvious.)

When sample size quadruples, the standard error is halved. In your example, sample size increased by a factor of 100, so standard error decreased by factor of 10. You can use this terminology and formula to find a suitable stat book to reference in your article.

Comment: Yes! That’s exactly what I need, a relation between variance and sample size.  This relationship will only be briefly mentioned in a paper I’m writing, but I needed some sort of proof to back it up for those who will be reviewing the paper.
If it gets accepted, I’ll post the paper in a week or two… in case you are interested. I am new to this election data stuff, and you wouldn’t believe how terrible the math is in some of the papers. 
Thanks again.

Comment: Put Addendum at end of my Answer. Yes, I would believe terrible math/stat in election statistics / polling literature. Some fields are worse. (Might nominate criminal justice.) // A common mistake with polling data: If the 'margin of sampling error' for the poll is 3% and Candidate X is polling at 54% it is common to say s/he is ahead of Candidate Y beyond the margin of error. But in a 2-person race, the margin of sampling error for a _difference_ is approx. twice the margin of error for one candidate. (Intuitively, almost every response _for_ X is a response _against_ Y.)

Comment: I'll take a look at that polling data addendum...
Here is the paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.11110
Click on 'PDF' in the upper right-hand corner.
Your input on this post is used on page 22 in the 'gerrymandering and historical data' section. Thanks again.